# OWASP ZAP: Add parameter to every request

Tags: zap

I am testing a website that makes heavily use of REST API endpoints. After authentication, the app adds the authentication token as part of every request in the form of:

```
OPTIONS
https://www.target.com/api/Action/some-action?data=foobar&access_token=THISISTHETOKEN
User-Agent: ...
Accept: */*
..
Host: target.com
Length: 0
```

How can I force that every request (inside the spider, scanner, etc.) uses this predefined parameter such that I can browser authenticated?

Update:

I tried creating a Http Sender Script but I fail at modifying the http url parameters:

```
function sendingRequest(msg, initiator, helper) {
    var token = org.parosproxy.paros.network.HtmlParameter
    token.setType(org.parosproxy.paros.network.HtmlParameter.Type.url)
    token.setName('access_token')
    token.setValue('foo')
    print('token: ' + String(token))
    msg.getUrlParams().add(token)
    print(msg.getUrlParams())
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can setup a [Replacer](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/replacer/) rule or create an [Http Sender script](https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/master/httpsender).

For a Replacer rule select the type as "Request Header String" then set the regex as something like `(http://example.org.*)` and the replacement something like `$1?myParamToAdd=someValue` (Note this replacer example is untested.)

For an HttpSender script something like the following should work:

```
var URL_TYPE    = org.parosproxy.paros.network.HtmlParameter.Type.url;
var HtmlParameter = Java.type('org.parosproxy.paros.network.HtmlParameter');

var paramName = 'myParamToAdd';
var paramValue = 'someValuetoAdd';

function sendingRequest(msg, initiator, helper) {
  if (!msg.getRequestHeader().getURI().toString().contains(paramName + '=' + paramValue)) {
    //You might want to add a check here for the proper domain or path as well..
    var urlParams = msg.getUrlParams();
    var newParam = new HtmlParameter(URL_TYPE, paramName, paramValue);
    urlParams.add(newParam); // you could print this if you need to see what's up
    msg.setGetParams(urlParams);
  }
  return msg;
}

function responseReceived(msg, initiator, helper) {
  //Nothing to do here
}
```

Comment: I was having a look at the replacer but it only allows modifying the headers. I am now working at creating a Http Sender script but I fail at adding a Http Parameter. My current script:

function sendingRequest(msg, initiator, helper) {
 var token = org.parosproxy.paros.network.HtmlParameter
 token.setType(org.parosproxy.paros.network.HtmlParameter.Type.url)
 token.setName('access_token')
 token.setValue('foo')
 print('token: ' + String(token))
        msg.getUrlParams().add(token)
}

Answer (score 1):

In the end the following HTTP Sender script worked for me:

```
var URL_TYPE   = org.parosproxy.paros.network.HtmlParameter.Type.url;
var authTokenName = 'access_token'
var authTokenValue = 'xrVNjdzmUomrpFcoyliUQYvfpgGPF5q8e2kCQNfhcs6pzO4yh22RACvSGNCeuMMg'

function sendingRequest(msg, initiator, helper) {
    var urlParams = msg.getUrlParams();
        // print ("Url Params before update: " + urlParams);
     var updatedUrlParams = modifyParams(urlParams);
     // print ("Url Params after update: " + updatedUrlParams);
     msg.setGetParams(updatedUrlParams);
}

function modifyParams(params) {
    var hasAccessToken = 0
    var iterator = params.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        var param = iterator.next();
        // Check if the url parameters has the antiCsrfTokenName in it.
       //print('param:' + param.getName())
        if (param.getName().equals(authTokenName)) {
            var secureTokenValue = param.getValue();
          print('[i] auth:' + secureTokenValue)
            hasAccessToken = 1            
        }
    }
    if(hasAccessToken==0){
        print('[i] no token. Update query.')

        var HtmlParameter = Java.type('org.parosproxy.paros.network.HtmlParameter')
        var newParam = new HtmlParameter(URL_TYPE, authTokenName, authTokenValue);

        params.add(newParam) 
        print('[i] mod auth:' + params) 

    }

    return params;
}


function responseReceived(msg, initiator, helper) {
    // Debugging can be done using println like this
    //print('responseReceived called for url=' + msg.getRequestHeader().getURI().toString())
}
```